# Spark Structured Streaming - unable to change max.poll.records (showing as 1)

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, spark-structured-streaming

i've a Spark structured streaming job which reads from Kafka, does processing and puts data into Mongo/Kafka/GCP Buckets (i.e. it is processing heavy)

I'm consistently seeing the following warnings:

```
22/09/06 16:55:03 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-4e7e7f32-19ab-44d5-99f5-59fb5a462af2-594190416-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-4e7e7f32-19ab-44d5-99f5-59fb5a462af2-594190416-driver-0] Member consumer-spark-kafka-source-4e7e7f32-19ab-44d5-99f5-59fb5a462af2-594190416-driver-0-1-604d740f-16d1-46b3-955c-502be5b02be1 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator 35.237.40.54:9094 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) due to consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

I'm trying to change the values of the parameters - max.poll.interval.ms & max.poll.records in the spark.readStream (shown below)

```
df_stream = spark.readStream.format('kafka') \
        .option("kafka.security.protocol", "SSL") \
        .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.location", ssl_truststore_location) \
        .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.password", ssl_truststore_password) \
        .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.location", ssl_keystore_location) \
        .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.password", ssl_keystore_password) \
        .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", kafkaBrokers) \
        .option("subscribe", topic) \
        .option("startingOffsets", "latest") \
        .option("failOnDataLoss", "false") \
        .option("kafka.metadata.max.age.ms", "1000") \
        .option("kafka.ssl.keystore.type", "PKCS12") \
        .option("kafka.ssl.truststore.type", "PKCS12") \
        .option("kafka.max.poll.interval.ms", 600000) \
        .option("kafka.max.poll.records", 7000) \
        .load()
```

Th values that i see in the KafkaConsumer are :

max.poll.interval.ms - 600000 (changed from 300000)
max.poll.records - not getting changed, it is showing as 1

```
22/09/07 02:29:32 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig: ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [34.138.213.152:9094]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = use_all_dns_ips
    client.id = consumer-spark-kafka-source-17ac0d19-f30c-4db7-91b9-1dbe9172829e-594190416-driver-0-1
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = spark-kafka-source-17ac0d19-f30c-4db7-91b9-1dbe9172829e-594190416-driver-0
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    internal.throw.on.fetch.stable.offset.unsupported = false
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 600000
    max.poll.records = 1
    metadata.max.age.ms = 1000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = SSL
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.engine.factory.class = null
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = syslog-vani-noacl.p12
    ssl.keystore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.keystore.type = PKCS12
    ssl.protocol = TLSv1.2
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = versa-kafka-gke-ca.p12
    ssl.truststore.password = [hidden]
    ssl.truststore.type = PKCS12
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArrayDeserializer
```

```
22/09/06 16:55:03 INFO org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator: [Consumer clientId=consumer-spark-kafka-source-4e7e7f32-19ab-44d5-99f5-59fb5a462af2-594190416-driver-0-1, groupId=spark-kafka-source-4e7e7f32-19ab-44d5-99f5-59fb5a462af2-594190416-driver-0] Member consumer-spark-kafka-source-4e7e7f32-19ab-44d5-99f5-59fb5a462af2-594190416-driver-0-1-604d740f-16d1-46b3-955c-502be5b02be1 sending LeaveGroup request to coordinator 35.237.40.54:9094 (id: 2147483645 rack: null) due to consumer poll timeout has expired. This means the time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than the configured max.poll.interval.ms, which typically implies that the poll loop is spending too much time processing messages. You can address this either by increasing max.poll.interval.ms or by reducing the maximum size of batches returned in poll() with max.poll.records.
```

Kafka documentation states that the default value of - max.poll.records = 500

so, few questions -

How do i change the value of max.poll.records to the desired value ?
Also, why is the value showing as 1, instead of the default value of 500 ?

Comment: I believe Spark explicitly overrides max poll records. Besides, you're currently getting the log with only one polled record? Then you're doing too much processing on just one event and increasing 7000x times definitely won't fix anything. Instead, focus on distributing your processing logic better. For example, process a record and write to a new topic. Consume new topics in two **different** jobs to write to Mongo and GCS **separately**. Or, you can use Kafka Connect to do the same rather than need Spark